# Joomfish direct link to translation

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomfish

I am developing a large multinational site that uses JoomFish 2.5.1 and I believe I have spotted a bug, or I am doing something wrong.

The problem I am having is whilst creating a workflow system for my translators I need to be able to link them directly to a backend page for the translation. I am using a URL in the form:

http://[SITE_URL]/administrator/index.php?option=com_joomfish&task=translate.edit&catid=k2_items&cid%5B0%5D=%7C237%7C8

Where the last variable is an array that contains the 'id', 'reference_id' and 'language_id' respectively from the #_jf_content table. In the form:

```
cid = array(
    [0] => id|reference_id|language_id
)
```

Which works fine, except for the language is not updated in the right hand panel when viewing the page. So say I am viewing a page and I change the language_id, the content on the page updates accordingly all except for the drop down language selection on the right. Which is causing a kink in my workflow system. It doesn't update at all in Chrome, seems to work better in Safari and Firefox. However I can't restrict my translators to specific browsers.

Any ideas on why this might be happening? And how to solve the issue.

Any help or incite would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now figured this out. For anyone else experiencing this problem, you need to add another parameter to the URL `&select_language_id=` and make this the same as the `language_id` used in the last variable in the `cid` array.